# Is this infinite product for zeta(2) trivial?

Tags: riemann-zeta, products, experimental-mathematics

I have crafted an infinite product for zeta(2) [shown here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94146/973) Euler's prime product is the only one I'm aware of. In checking [Math World,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html) I don't see any products. Is that because they are trivial?

Comment: On the page linked above, we find some interesting patterns. The mathematics may be trivial, but the patterns might not be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your product can be easily rewritten as $\dfrac B{A^2}$, where $A=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\dfrac{x^2}{n^2}\bigg)$ with $x=\dfrac16$, and

$B=\displaystyle\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^3+1}{n^3-1}$, which, believe it or not, is telescopic, and yields a rational number as result.

$(B$ has been evaluated on this site *several* times$)$. So the answer to your question is **yes**.

Comment: Is $A$ evaluated using the infinite product for $\sin$ or something similar?

Comment: I found $B$ on this site. $A$ I found several years ago.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus: Yes.